# is it possible to add a a-href link to a user in a facebook wall post?

Tags: facebook

when you post a message using the facebookSDK, i was wondering if it is possible to add a link to another user profile?.

Something like:

> **Carl** has left a message to **Julian**, **Ana** using the "Send Message" application

where Carl, Julian and Ana are links to their respective profile pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unfortunately you cannot tag people (friends) in that way using the api. I searched for ever to find a way for doing it, but it cannot be done.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.I too tried the same . But facebook allows only plaintext to be posted as message to the wall.

Its better to drop the idea

Answer (score 0):

Facebook now allows to tag poeple inside actions : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/#taggingpeople